# Facebook ads-api: what are the adgroup_status field's values?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

We'd like to get the complete list of values that the adgroup_status field can take. According to [the FB docco](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup) it cannot assume the value CAMPAIGN_GROUP_PAUSED but we get that via the API.

Can someone supply the actual list of values this field may assume? In our code I see 14 values but it's likely incorrect/outdated:

- ACTIVE
- DELETED
- PENDING_REVIEW
- DISAPPROVED
- PENDING_BILLING_INFO
- CAMPAIGN_PAUSED
- ADGROUP_PAUSED
- NA
- CAMPAIGN_GROUP_PAUSED
- PAUSED
- CREDIT_CARD_NEEDED
- PREAPPROVED
- DISABLED
- ARCHIVED

Comment: What is the API call you are making that gets you CAMPAIGN_GROUP_PAUSED? Are you sure you aren't sending the request to an ad set or a campaign?

Comment: the URL is https://graph.facebook.com/<account>/adgroups

Comment: The full API call, please :) Update your question above with the cURL call or any other SDK call you are making.

Answer (score 1):

these are the adgroup_status which we get we haven't seen any other apart from these. 'ARCHIVED' is to be added in the next migration changes. (refer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api/best-practices/storing_adobjects))

```
'ACTIVE'
'PAUSED'
'CAMPAIGN_PAUSED'
'CAMPAIGN_GROUP_PAUSED'
'DELETED'
'PENDING_REVIEW'
'PREAPPROVED'
'DISAPPROVED'
'PENDING_BILLING_INFO'
'ADGROUP_PAUSED'
'CREDIT_CARD_NEEDED'
```

Comment: thanks, nice to hear from someone else in the trenches :)  Still trying to get my head around archived/deleted, thanks for the link